# How can I convert an AngularJS Javascript controller to Typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a very simple controller:

```
.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, $userService) {

        $scope.ok = function () {
            $modalInstance.close();
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    })
```

How can I change this so that it uses typescript and so it will work even after I minify my javascript?

Comment: Valid JavaScript is valid TypeScript - congratulations, you did it.

Comment: @Marty True, and a good point. But there are some other advantages to making it use the native TypeScript class capabilities (and such) to clean it up and make it a little more maintainable at scale. I say that just in case that's your "unclear" VTC--it's good to know how to benefit from TypeScript, when you'll be using it anyway. Even if you don't *have* to.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen Of course - I was being a little cheeky.

Comment: @Marty Alright, just making sure. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Controllers and services can become classes.

I like to use `$inject` so it's safe to minify, but that line is optional.

```
class ModalInstanceController {
    static $inject = ["$scope", "$modalInstance", "$userService"];
    constructor($scope, $modalInstance, $userService) {

        $scope.ok = () => {
            $modalInstance.close();
        };

        $scope.cancel = () => {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    }
}
```

```
.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ModalInstanceController);
```

Including `$inject` is equivalent to using the array syntax in vanilla JavaScript:

```
.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ["$scope", "$modalInstance", "$userService", function ($scope, $modalInstance, $userService) { ... }]);
```

---

In a real-world application, I like to avoid the use of `$scope` except for things that actually need it (like `$watch`), in which case I'd pull the methods out as well. This will require a change to your HTML, though.

```
class ModalInstanceController {
    private $modalInstance : any;

    static $inject = ["$modalInstance", "$userService"];
    constructor($modalInstance, $userService) {
        this.$modalInstance = $modalInstance;
    }

    ok() {
        this.$modalInstance.close();
    }
    cancel() {
        this.$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}
```

Then in your HTML,

```
<button type="button" ng-click="ModalInstanceCtrl.ok()">OK</button>
```

Note the use of the fully-qualified `ModalInstanceCtrl.ok()`, since it's no longer just floating around in the scope.

---

Just since you caught me when I was bored, here's a nice advantage of using TypeScript, since I see you have `$userService`.

```
class UserService {
    // A parameterized constructor is, of course, allowed here too.
    // Optionally supply $inject, per above

    parse(arg : string) {
        return parseInt(arg);
    }
}

class ModalInstanceController {
    private $modalInstance : any;
    private $userService : UserService; // Note the typing here

    static $inject = ["$modalInstance", "$userService"];
    // Explicit typing here is optional, since "any" will cast automatically
    // but I like to be clear anyway.
    constructor($modalInstance, $userService : UserService) {
        this.$modalInstance = $modalInstance;
        this.$userService = $userService;
    }

    ok() {
        // you'll get Intellisense here, whilst still benefiting from DI from Angular
        var arg = this.$userService.parse("12");

        this.$modalInstance.close();
    }
    cancel() {
        this.$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}
```

```
app.service("$userService", UserService);
app.controller("ModalInstanceCtrl", ModalInstanceController);
```